# The relation between the number of square-free divisors of n and the Möbius $\mu$- function.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, mobius-function

I was solving this problem:

> Let $S(n)$ denote the number of squarefree divisors of $n$. Establish that
>   $$ S(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} \lvert \mu(d) \rvert = 2^{\omega(n)},$$
>   where $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime divisors of $n$.

But I do not understand why the first equality is correct (for the second equality I have no problem), could anyone explain it for me?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you describe the square-free divisors of $n$ in terms of the prime factors of $n$?

Comment: I have edited your post to not rely on an image copy of the text. Images are poor for several reasons. One reason is that users who are visually impaired may not be able to read the post. Another reason is that search engines cannot access the text within the image, making the post more challenging to find for later readers. I note that your post is a copy of a problem from some text: it would be helpful for you to add in the source to your post as well. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, the möbius function takes one of the values $-1, 0, 1$. We know that $\mu(n) = 0$ if $n$ is not squarefree, and $\mu(n) = \pm 1$ if $n$ is squarefree. Thus $\lvert \mu(n) \rvert$ is the squarefree indicator function --- it is $1$ if and only if its argument is squarefree.

$S(n)$ counts the number of squarefree divisors. One way to count this is to look at all the divisors and add $1$ for every squarefree divisor: and this is precisely what the sum does.